# How to get Bill's age

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a word problem here and I still don't know how to solve this. Please help me. Thank you.

"Bill, my second oldest, is twice as old as one of my three other children. Joan is three times as old as one of other two children, John and Jean. John is four times as old as Jean who is $1$ year old. How old is Bill?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Jean : $1$**

**John : $4$**

Joan can be either $3*1=3$ or $3*4=12$.

Bill is twice as old as one of the other three. So his age can be $2*1=2$ or $2*4=8$ or $2*3=6$ or $2*12=36$. But Bill is also the second oldest.

We can eliminate Joan being $3$, because that case would only lead us to Bill being the youngest or the eldest but not the second oldest. So,

**Joan : $12$**

Now finally we can conclude that Bill's age should be $8$ as that is the only possibility that makes him the second oldest. So,

**Bill : $8$**

**Jean:$1$, John:$4$, Bill:$8$, Joan:$12$**

Comment: thank you. Will you show me the solution how did it goes?

Comment: @user122935 Hope the answer is clear enough !

Answer (score 0):

Work from the end, Jean's age=$1$ years, John's age=$4$ years. Therefore, Joan's age can be either of $3$ years or $12$ years (three times as old as one of other two children).

Now, if Bill's age is twice Jean's or Joan's, he can not be second oldest. So, the only possibility is that Bill's age is twice John's, i.e. $8$ years.